# history.js bookmark support

Tags: bookmarks, history.js

I change the history state of the browser using history.js. Let's say I use this code:

```
History.pushState({someState:2}, null, "?someState=2");
```

binding to the statechange event, it is easy to change the page based on the contents of History.state.data, but History.state is not set when the page is loaded initially (when someone saves the url in a bookmark for example). So I guess I should use the query string in that case (the ?someState=2 part of the URL). When using a fallback for 'HTML4-browsers', I guess I'll have to use the hash part of the URL. My question: does history.js provide an easy way to do all this, or is it really only for history, not for bookmarks?

I hope the question is clear..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `History.getState()` ?

Comment: Yes, but when a user bookmarks the link (or copies it into another tab or clicks on it in an email or whatever) there is no state exept for the URL. So I am looking for something like deparam() that the BBQ library provides (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/).